# Why is Jackson not deserializing some XML elements?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-deserialization

Once I get the XML as a string, I want to deserialize it. The idea of my deserializer is that I can tell it which type I want to deserialize some xml input to and it will return a deserialized object of that type to me.

#### My code

This is my deserialization method:

```
public <T> T deserialize(String input, Class<T> type) throws JsonProcessingException {

        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        return mapper.readValue(input, type);
    }
```

My XML input contains a `<TripList>` element as the root element. It further consists of many other elements and the most important of them is the `<Trip>` element.

Here is a brief example of my XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TripList scrB="x" serverVersion="1.1.12" dialectVersion="2.22" planRtTs="unknown" requestId="abc" xmlns="http://hacon.de/hafas/proxy/hafas-proxy">
    <Trip idx="0" tripId="C-0" ctxRecon="" duration="PT5H33M" rtDuration="PT5H33M" checksum="31623617" transferCount="3">
        <Origin/>
        <Destination/>
        ...
```

#### POJO classes

`TripList` POJO class looks like this:

```
XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "TripList", propOrder = {
    "trip",
    "pricing",
    "sotContext"
})
public class TripList
    extends CommonResponseType
{

    @XmlElement(name = "Trip")
    protected List<TripType> trip;
    @XmlElement(name = "Pricing")
    protected List<PricingType> pricing;
    @XmlElement(name = "SotContext")
    protected SotContextType sotContext;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "scrB")
    protected String scrB;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "scrF")
    protected String scrF;
    ...
```

`TripType` POJO class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "TripType", propOrder = {
    "origin",
    "destination",
    "messages",
    "notes",
    ...
})
public class TripType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Origin")
    protected OriginDestType origin;
    @XmlElement(name = "Destination")
    protected OriginDestType destination;
    @XmlElement(name = "Messages")
    protected Messages messages;
    @XmlElement(name = "Notes")
    ...
```

#### Problem

**After calling the deserialize() method, the TripType attribute (Trip element in XML input) inside the TripList object is null.** Also other elements are null while XML attributes are correctly deserialized.

Here is an example from my debugger with different values inside XML input:

[image: Debugger log]

Comment: When your lists are not wrapped you need to let the `ObjectMapper` know `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)`

Comment: @kendavidson could you explain that a little more? It seems to solve my issue. Yet I’d like to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

@PeMa, sure.

When using the example provided by @Chuck Nuris the xml looks like this

```
<TripList>
  <Trip>...</Trip>
  <Trip>...</Trip>
  <Trip>...</Trip>
</TripList>
```

When working with xml the (more accepted) way of doing things in general is:

```
<TripList>
  <Trips>
    <Trip>...</Trip>
    <Trip>...</Trip>
    <Trip>...</Trip>
  </Trips>
</TripList>
```

While working with the object:

```
class TripList {
   List<Trip> trips;
}
```

Because the more general way to use XML is to **wrap** this list in the `<Trips>` element, the default functionality for Jackson XML is to expect:

The name of the variable `trips` to match the wrapper element `<Trips>` when (de)serializing.  When there is no wrapper element `<Trips>` in this case then you need to tell Jackson that the list of `<Trip>` are not wrapped.

When working with wrapping you can:

- turn it off `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)`
- change the name `JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "MyTrips")`

based on what you want or have to deal with your example being.